# Matlab: Using the warp function to map an image onto a sphere

Tags: matlab

I am attempting to map, or have an image on a sphere. My current code is:

```
[x,y,z]=sphere(100);
imgRGB = imread('peppers.png');
warp(x,y,z,imgRGB);

surf(x,y,z);
material([0.1 0.9 1]);
h = light;
for az = -360:5:360
  lightangle(h,az,30)
  pause(0.1);
end
```

The problem i am having is that the image does not appear. Would this be because i have not loaded the image into Matlab?

Comment: You've loaded the image all right, it's built-in in MATLAB.

Comment: So why does the image not appear on the sphere?

Comment: You're plotting two different plots on the same figure,  but the second plot is overwriting the first one.  All you need is the first three lines of code.